# Eliminar elementos de un array map

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un `array` el cual proporciona varios nombres, la cuestión es que necesito excluir varios nombres para que no se tengan en cuenta.

El código que utilizo es,

```
cuentas.map(n => n.cuenta.nombre)
```

Entonces me devuelve estos valores.

```
data=['Juan', 'Felipe', 'Gustavo', 'Ernesto', 'Mario', 'Luis', 'Juanma', 'Jose', 'Eduardo', 'Alex'];
```

Necesito poder eliminar por ejemplo a `Ernesto, Jose y Felipe`, y que me devuelva el resto de valores.

He intentado con algo así,

```
data.filter((item) => { return data.indexOf("Jose", "Felipe") != -1 }).map((item)=> { console.log(item); });
```

Pero no me sirve, también he visto con reduce pero no logro hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón por la que no te funciona usando [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), es porque la estas usando mal.

> cadena.indexOf(valorBusqueda[, indiceDesde])

#### Solución:

Usando `array.filter` podrías hacer estos cambios:

- Crear un arreglo con los nombre que se desea eliminar
- En la función *"filtradora"* controlamos el nombre no este dentro del arreglo anterior

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let data = ['Juan', 'Felipe', 'Gustavo', 'Ernesto', 'Mario', 'Luis', 'Juanma', 'Jose', 'Eduardo', 'Alex'];
let remove = ['Ernesto', 'Jose', 'Felipe'];
let result = data.filter(item => !remove.includes(item));
console.log(result)
```

---

Referencias:

- [`string.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Tal cual mencionas, estaba complicando más el código tu respuesta es lo que estaba intentando hacer.